# embedded linux clients and authentication

Tags: web-services, authentication

I need to come up with a scheme for remote devices running linux to push data to a web service via https.  I'm not sure how I want to handle authentication.  Can anyone see any security risks by including some kind of authentication in the body of the request itself?  I'm thinking of having the request body be JSON, and it would look like this:

```
{
  'id':'some unique id',
  'password':'my password',
  'data':1234
}
```

If the id and password in the JSON don't match what is in my database, the request gets rejected.

Is there a problem with this?  Is there a better way to ensure that only my clients can push data?

Answer (score 0):

That scheme is primitive, but it works.

Usually a real session is preferred since it offers some advantages:

- separation of authentication and request
- history of requests in a session
- credentials get sent only once for multiple requests
- flexible change of authentication strategy
- ...

Comment: Thanks. What authentication scheme would you choose for the Linux based clients I described?  There are so many choices.

Comment: That depends on the environment: what capabilities of the https server you use (i assume you chose https as transport layer) and the authority you want to authenticate against. IN case of apache as https server you have a wealth of authentication modules to chose from. As said, that depends on the authority you want to authenticate against. 

I created a few APIs where I combined http basic or digest authentication with a RESTful API. Simple, yet flexible.